# how to marge the values of column in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

Lets consider this query

```
select class_id,case when event_id=2 then sum(time_spent) end as timespent ,case when event_id=3 then sum(timespent) end as visitedtimespent from class group by class_id,event_id;
```

output is looking like

```
class_id     timespent visitedtimespent

1             2000       NULL
1             NULL        10
2             4000       NULL
2             NULL        5
```

when I use this query

```
select class_id,case when event_id=2 then sum(time_spent) end as timespent ,case when event_id=3 then sum(time_spent) end as timespent from class group by class_id;
```

output is looking like

```
class_id     timespent visitedtimespent

1             2000       NULL
2             4000       NULL
```

but I expected this output

```
class_id     timespent visitedtimespent

1             2000        10
2             4000         5
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
select class_id,
       sum(case when event_id=2 then time_spent else 0 end) as timespent, 
       sum(case when event_id=3 then time_spent else 0 end) as visitedtimespent
from class 
group by class_id
```

Answer (score 0):

sum the case.

```
    select class_id,
sum(case when event_id=2 then time_spent end) as timespent ,
sum(case when event_id=3 then time_spent end) as visitedtimespent
from class group by class_id;
```

to explain the difference:
`case when id... then sum(value)` is equivalent to

```
select case when id then value from
(
    select id, sum(value) as value from table
)subquery
```

which is an illegal grouping(ID is not aggregated or included in grouping, so the ID value will be chosen at random between all existing entries), and your ID information will be lost. IF you then apply a case to the ID info, you will not get relevant results.

Comment: Thanks both the answer are useful,but why the sum differs from inside the case and outside the case,due to the group by function,any link to refer is much more helpfull